# Как запретить загружать текст в html дальше, если шрифты еще не загрузились

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

У юзеров с плохим интернетом загружается сначала доступный на пк шрифт, а через некоторое время загружается нормальный (нужный) шрифт и из-за этого происходит резкий скачок текста, некая вспышка, которой быть не должно, как можно запретить браузеру загружать html страницу пока не загрузился основной шрифт?

Comment: Что за вспышка, что за скачок, как это выглядит...?

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут preload?

[Предварительная загрузка шрифтов](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/470870/)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)